# No funciona el widget de html, code highlight plugin elementor pro - wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugin, widget, elementor

Estoy desarrollando un sitio web con Wordpress mediante un plugin llamado **elementor pro**, el cual tiene una herramienta o widget que permite colocar código Javascript y no esta funcionando. Reinstale el tema, Wordpress y el plugin pero persiste el problema. Elimine el widget también para probar si añadiendo uno nuevo solucionaba el error pero sin éxito.

Adjunto una captura del widget, el cual no me deja ni escribir ni modificar el código como podía anteriormente antes de que surgiera el error o bug. Conste que surgió el error luego de actualizar el **elementor pro** pero reinstalé y volví a una versión anterior y el problema persiste por lo que no se por donde se encuentra la raíz del problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: WordPress ya utiliza jquery, no necesitas volver a ponerlo, ademas tu html esta mal, estas re agregando la etiqueta head, eso es un error de sintaxis, si tu codigo no funciona seguramente es porque usas la variable $ para tus funciones, necesitas usar la variable jQuery() o decirle a jQuery el uso de la variable $, por favor lee un poco más sobre jQuery, javascript y el desarrollo en wordpress. Tambien te invito a leer [ask] y hacer el [tour]

Comment: @JefferzonBol , muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Ya elimine el head y el llamado de la libreria e igualmente en ese caso funciona bien el codigo. El problema es el widget en si mismo que no me esta dejando modificar el codigo, si lo pude hacer cuando utilizo el modo incognito pero en caso normal el codigo esta como la imagen que adjunte y todavia no descubro el motivo. No es la cache por lo que pude comprobar.